# WIndows 10 generates beep on locked screen... why?

Tags: windows-10, notifications

I have quite annoying problem with my laptop. I leave it running pretty much all the time but with turning off and locking the screen. Unfortunately, one the system goes into lock mode it starts to play default beep sound once in a while. I tried to catch it by getting to the computer immediately after it happens but it still requires some time (get from sofa to my desk, unlock screen with fingerprint)... anyway, there's no notification there.

The device is Dell XPS 15 9500 with Dell WD19 docking station. Station has external drive, logitech receiver and 2 external monitors conected.

How can I find what triggers that sound to resolve the issue? I don't want to fully disable the sound because I want keep getting reasonable notifications. Instead I want to find out what is it informing me about and address it somehow.

What I have already tried:

1. I disabled `USB selective suspend setting` in advanced Power Options
2. I disabled `Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power` for all USB devices in Device Manager
3. I disabled `Show notifications on the lock screen` and `Allow notifications to play sounds` in Notifications & actions settings

And I still get this beeping... :/

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the Sounds tab and found that the two common beeps I would hear during the screen lock were associated with device connect and disconnect.  I have an external monitor, so guessing that may be the culprit.  Since I dont really care for any system notifications, I have now disabled them (I had the option of Windows default or no sound in the Control Panel/Sound/Sounds tab, and that seems to have quieted things down!

Answer (score 0):

Devices connecting and disconnecting without your input (malfunctioning) could be something to do with the firmware.

Hardware-based problems are usually firmware or physically damaged components, in my decade-long tech support experience.

At my place of employment, we see problems with newly deployed laptops using docking stations that are often resolved with firmware updates.

Update your firmware. Restart. Check for more updates.

I'd also be interested to know if unplugging everything you can then waiting a while to see if the beep persists. After an indeterminate, non-specific amount of time later, reattach the devices one by one and wait for beeps in order to narrow it down.